# Selecionar todos os registros de uma tabela com Groovy

Tags: script, groovy, resultset

Preciso pegar todos os registros de uma tabela a partir de um `script` em **Groovy**, porém com o `script` que criei ele está pegando apenas um registro de cada coluna e fora de ordem também. Meu `script` esta assim:

```
List result = new ArrayList();
def i = 1;
while (resultset.next()){
    List sousListe = new ArrayList();
    sousListe.add(resultset.getString(i));

    result.add(sousListe);
    i = i + 1;
}

return result;
```

Inicialmente ele pegava apenas todos os registros da primeira coluna, dai para isso meu `script` estava assim:

```
List result = new ArrayList();
while (resultset.next()){
    List sousListe = new ArrayList();
    sousListe.add(resultset.getString(1));

    result.add(sousListe);
}

return result;
```

Por isso pensei que se criasse uma variável que se implementasse dentro no meu `while` ele percorreria todas as colunas da minha tabela porém apenas o erro que mudou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido o problema, precisava primeiro descobrir o número de colunas que meu `ResultSet` e então realizar um `While` até que o número de colunas acabasse assim passou a exibir todos os registros corretamente, segue `script` correto:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
Logger logger= Logger.getLogger("org.bonitasoft");
List result = new ArrayList();

if (resultset.last()){
    def l = resultset.getRow();
    def i = resultset.metaData.columnCount;
    resultset.beforeFirst();
    logger.info("Numero de Linhas do ResultSet: "+l.toString());
    logger.info("Numero de Colunas do ResultSet: "+i.toString());

    while (resultset.next()){
        List sousListe = new ArrayList();
        def x = 1;
        while (x <= i){
            sousListe.add(resultset.getString(x));
            logger.info(resultset.getString(x));
            x++ ;
        }
    result.add(sousListe);

    }
}
return result;
```